# The colon does not align with the \vdots

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I have the following code to align several equations:

```
\begin{aligned}
s_{1} & :=\sum_{1 \leq j \leq m} X_{j} \\
s_{2} & :=\sum_{1 \leq j<k \leq m} X_{j} \cdot X_{k} \\
      & \vdots \\
s_{k} & :=\sum_{1 \leq j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{k} \leq m} X_{j_{1}} \cdot X_{j_{2}} \cdot \cdots \cdot X_{j_{k}} \\
      & \vdots \\
s_{m} & :=X_{1} X_{2} \cdots X_{m}
\end{aligned}
```

[image: LaTeX output of above code with only minimal.cls and amsmath.sty]

I would like to ask why the colon does not align with the vdots and a solution for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! It does not align because a colon is a relation, i.e. of the `\mathrel` type. If you want to align it "by hand" you could just make the `\vdots` of that type, too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
s_{1} & :=\sum_{1 \leq j \leq m} X_{j} \\
s_{2} & :=\sum_{1 \leq j<k \leq m} X_{j} \cdot X_{k} \\
      & \mathrel{\vdots} \\
s_{k} & :=\sum_{1 \leq j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{k} \leq m} X_{j_{1}} \cdot X_{j_{2}} \cdot \cdots \cdot X_{j_{k}} \\
      & \mathrel{\vdots}\\
s_{m} & :=X_{1} X_{2} \cdots X_{m}
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solutions is elegant and works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

I don't think these should align on the dots of `:=`, but rather should be centered with respect to either the `s_k` or perhaps the relation `:=`.  The dots in `:=` serve a different function to those in `\vdots`.  The package `mathtools` provides the command `\vdotswithin{...}` for centering such `\vdots` with respect to the material `...`; it also provides `\coloneqq` for a better version of `:=`:

[image: Sample outpu]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  s_{1} &\coloneqq\sum_{1 \leq j \leq m} X_{j} \\
  s_{2} &\coloneqq\sum_{1 \leq j<k \leq m} X_{j} \cdot X_{k} \\
  \vdotswithin{s_{k}}& \\
  s_{k} &\coloneqq\sum_{1 \leq j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{k} \leq m}
          X_{j_{1}} \cdot X_{j_{2}} \cdot \cdots \cdot X_{j_{k}} \\
  \vdotswithin{s_{k}}& \\
  s_{m} &\coloneqq X_{1} X_{2} \cdots X_{m}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  s_{1} &\coloneqq\sum_{1 \leq j \leq m} X_{j} \\
  s_{2} &\coloneqq\sum_{1 \leq j<k \leq m} X_{j} \cdot X_{k} \\
        &\vdotswithin{\coloneqq} \\
  s_{k} &\coloneqq\sum_{1 \leq j_{1}<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{k} \leq m}
          X_{j_{1}} \cdot X_{j_{2}} \cdot \cdots \cdot X_{j_{k}} \\
        &\vdotswithin{\coloneqq} \\
  s_{m} &\coloneqq X_{1} X_{2} \cdots X_{m}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same (I prefer the dots centered on the equals sign). Assuming the colons are necessary (they aren't, in my opinion), the vertical dots meaning ellipsis have nothing to do with those colons, so aligning them is out of question.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of changing of the answer given by the user @marmot using:

- The macro `\coegual` instead of `:=` simply because it provides the perfect alignment between `:` and `=`;
- Using the negative space with the command `\mkern` I tried to bring the products of the elements close to the summation because I do not like them distant;
- I have used `\substack` command because the subscripts on the summation did not bring me the products far away.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\coegual}{\mathrel{\mathop:}=}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
s_{1} & \coegual \sum_{1 \leq j \leq m} X_{j} \\
s_{2} & \coegual \sum_{1 \leq j < k \leq m} \mkern-5mu X_{j} \cdot X_{k}  \\
      & \mathrel{\vdots} \\
s_{k} & \coegual 
\sum_{\substack{1 \leq j_{1}< j_{2} <\cdots\\ \cdots< j_{k} \leq m}} \mkern-15mu X_{j_{1}} \cdot X_{j_{2}} \cdot \cdots \cdot X_{j_{k}} \\
      & \mathrel{\vdots}\\
s_{m} & \coegual X_{1} X_{2} \cdots X_{m}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```