# The equations do not align with respect to +

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I have the following code to align a system of equations

```
\begin{aligned}
p       &= q r             &+ r_0 \\
r       &= q_0 r_0         &+ r_1 \\
r_0     &= q_1 r_1         &+ r_2 \\
r_k     &= q_{k+1} r_{k+1} &+ r_{k+2} \\
        &\mathrel{\vdots} \\
r_{k+1} &= q_{k+2} r_{k+2}
\end{aligned}
```

[image]

I can not understand why these equations do not align w.r.t +.

Please help me explain this phenomenon!

Comment: A general explanation of how elements of equations are treated by the `align` environment is given in this answer: [Aligning equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124141/579)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one more `&` to have stuff left-aligned after it (if you want to work with `aligned` here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
p       &= q r             &&+ r_0 \\
r       &= q_0 r_0         &&+ r_1 \\
r_0     &= q_1 r_1         &&+ r_2 \\
r_k     &= q_{k+1} r_{k+1} &&+ r_{k+2} \\
        &\mathrel{\vdots} \\
r_{k+1} &= q_{k+2} r_{k+2} \\
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to center the `\vdots`, you can use the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
p       &= q r             &&+ r_0 \\
r       &= q_0 r_0         &&+ r_1 \\
r_0     &= q_1 r_1         &&+ r_2 \\
r_k     &= q_{k+1} r_{k+1} &&+ r_{k+2} \\
        &\vdotswithin{=} \\
r_{k+1} &= q_{k+2} r_{k+2} \\
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it. Could you please instruct me to put the \cdots right below the center of =?

Comment: @LeAnhDung I added something that does it. (Andrew Swann used this trick in an answer to a previous question of yours: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/494424/121799.)

Comment: I admire your great memory :)

Comment: @LeAnhDung Those who live in burrows need it otherwise they cannot find out. ;-)

Comment: @marmot such a nice suggestion....

Answer (score 3):

You need `alignedat`, that doesn't add horizontal spacing, but with one `&` more.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{alignedat}{2}
p       &= q r             &&+ r_0 \\
r       &= q_0 r_0         &&+ r_1 \\
r_0     &= q_1 r_1         &&+ r_2 \\
        &\mathrel{\;\vdots} \\
r_k     &= q_{k+1} r_{k+1} &&+ r_{k+2} \\
r_{k+1} &= q_{k+2} r_{k+2}
\end{alignedat}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm happy to see you on TexExchange ;)

Comment: @Akira Happy to see you, too!